# error forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred matrix multiplication

Tags: fortran, matrix-multiplication

I tried to implement an easy Matrix multiplication, but I Keep getting the error

```
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
test_performance.  00000000004708F1  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
test_performance.  000000000046F047  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
test_performance.  000000000043F544  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
test_performance.  000000000043F356  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
test_performance.  0000000000423DFF  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
test_performance.  000000000040384D  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libpthread.so.0    00002AD8B44769F0  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
test_performance.  00000000004034A8  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
test_performance.  0000000000402ECE  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc.so.6          00002AD8B46A6BE5  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
test_performance.  0000000000402DD9  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

This is my Code:

```
PROGRAM test_performance
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER ::  DIM_M, DIM_L, DIM_N, index1, index2,index3,index4
INTEGER, DIMENSION(4,4) :: A,B,C

DIM_L=4
DIM_M=4
DIM_N=4


DO index1=1,DIM_M
        DO index2=1,DIM_L
        print *, 'here I am!'
                A(index1,index2)=index1+index2
        END DO
END DO

DO index3=1,DIM_L
        DO index4=1,DIM_N
                B(index3,index4)=index3+index4
        END DO
END DO
        print *,'A= ',A
        print *,'B= ',B
        CALL MATRIXMULTIPLICATION

        PRINT *, 'C=', C



END PROGRAM test_performance


SUBROUTINE MATRIXMULTIPLICATION(A,B,C, DIM_M, DIM_L, DIM_N)
INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: DIM_M, DIM_L, DIM_N
INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: A(4,4), B(4,4)
INTEGER, INTENT(OUT) ::  C(4,4)

INTEGER :: ii=1,jj=1, kk=1

DO ii=1, DIM_M
        DO jj=1, DIM_N
                DO kk=1, DIM_L
                        C(ii,jj)=C(ii,jj)+A(ii,ll)*B(ll,jj)
                END DO
        END DO
END DO
END SUBROUTINE MATRIXMULTIPLICATION
```

I don't know why I get this error, since the Dimension and all the Indices should just be fine. I tried to find the error by using all possible stuff, but I don't havy any clue anymore what the error could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
CALL MATRIXMULTIPLICATION
```

doesn't include the arguments needed when the routine is called.  A poor solution would be to simply replace that statement by

```
CALL MATRIXMULTIPLICATION(A,B,C, DIM_M, DIM_L, DIM_N)
```

A better solution would be, however, to make the subroutine's interface *explicit*.  There are a number of ways of doing this, one by putting it into a `module` and `use`ing the module.  For a single subroutine that might be overkill but is definitely the way to go as your programs become larger and more complex.

A simple straightforward and satisfactory for your current purposes solution would be to move the line

```
END PROGRAM test_performance
```

to follow the line

```
END SUBROUTINE MATRIXMULTIPLICATION
```

and, where the `end program` line originally was insert the line

```
contains
```

If you had written your program along these lines in the first place the compiler would have seen your egregious error and pointed it out to you.  As it stands the subroutine is *external* to the program and the compiler can't match its dummy and actual arguments at compile time; as written that argument matching is the programmer's responsibility, one you've rather fluffed.

Further improvements would be to make your subroutine handle arrays of any size and to not bother passing the array dimensions through the argument list.  Fortran arrays carry their size and shape information with them, on the rare occasion a routine needs to know them explicitly it can make enquiries.

Even easier would be to use the `matmul` intrinsic and to spend your time programming other, perhaps more challenging and more interesting, parts of your code.

Comment: Further to this, using `contains` would extend the scope of the `implicit none` to the subroutine and the non declaration of `ll` would be caught. As it is, who knows what is happening in the main loop.